# Computer in workgroup asking for administrator password upon after restart

Tags: windows-7, workgroup

I was trying to connect my laptop to my PC to transfer some files. I followed some instruction I found from the web to do this. So here's what happened:

(This applies for both computers)

1. Under Network and Sharing Center, clicked "Connection: LAN", clicked Properties, IPv4, entered the ff. IP:
   Computer 1: 192.168.0.1
   Computer 2: 192.168.0.2
2. Opened Computer Properties, then Change Settings, assigned a workgroup name, then restart
3. After restart, both computers are asking for Administrator password

My problem here is I did not set a password, or I don't even know if I had to properly set up a workgroup first before using it. I do not know what password to enter. Now I can't use both computers.

Is there a default password for workgroups? Or is there a way to remove the workgroup setting? Can this be done on the PC only (because I already had the laptop rebuilt since it is needed urgently)?

Comment: Did you try entering your own password there?

Comment: Yes I did but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The happened because you ignored the warning when leaving the domain to make sure you know the local admin password.  You will have to use a local admin recovery tool (locksmith as an example) to recover the admin passwords.